# How to create a series of rectangles with a single loop using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to draw a series of rectangles given the values stored in a list.

For starters, nested loop is often the way to go. However, after some tests, it turned out to be a very bad idea.

Here's an example:

```
bs = 20
x_values = ['3', '4', '5', '6']
y_values = ['11', '11', '11', '11']

for X in x_values:
    for Y in y_values:
        x1 = int(X) * bs
        y1 = int(Y) * bs
        x2 = int(x1) + bs
        y2 = int(y1) + bs
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='red', width=1,outline='white', tag='obj')
```

Needless to say that this is a **terrible** idea. For something of small size such as this, it may work fine. However, if the list of elements increases, that would cause problems. All in all, this method is a no go.

After some research, I tried something else.

```
bs = 20
x_values = ['3', '4', '5', '6']
y_values = ['11', '11', '11', '11']

canvas.create_rectangle([int(X) * bs for X in x],
                    [int(Y) * bs for Y in y],
                    [(int(X) * bs) + bs for X in x],
                    [(int(Y) * bs) + bs for Y in y])
```

What I was trying to do is quite simple. Instead of looping through all the values linearly as before, I decided to generate the elements **on the fly**, that is, the for loop returns the value, Tkinter reads it and uses it as coordinates. Then when the next value will be generated, the last one will be dumped.

For one reason or another, Tkinter is reading all the variable at once and returning an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 16
```

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Those are list comprehensions, i.e. you are generating lists, not integers. It's not called `create_rectangles()` :-) So your first approach seems the way to go (though you are not clearly stating what you want to achieve). How many rectangles are you trying to create?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with your first method is that it draws four rectangles at each of four positions (i.e. `(3,11)`,`(4,11)`,`(5,11)` and `(6,11)`). Do you perhaps want to only draw one rectangle at each of those locations?

Comment: As you can see, there are 4 elements in the list, thus four rectangles

Comment: @FamousJameous that is the case. I only want to draw one rectangle at each of those locations.

Comment: Given an `x_values` with four numbers, and `y_values` with four numbers, how many rectangles are you wanting to draw? One? Four? Sixteen?

Comment: In this case only four

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to draw four rectangles, you can combine your two lists of x and y coordinates into one list of x,y pairs with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
coords = zip(x_values, y_values)
```

this will result in the following:

```
[('3', '11'), ('4', '11'), ('5', '11'), ('6', '11')]
```

If you now want to draw four rectangles, with each of those coordinates being used to define the actual coordinates, you can loop over each pair like this:

```
for x1, y1 in zip(x_values, y_values):
    x1 = int(x1) * bs
    y1 = int(y1) * bs
    x2 = x1 + bs
    y2 = y1 + bs
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill="red")
```